# Need help decoding the results of scapy.sr1 for both IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: networking, ipv6, scapy, ipv4

I have the following code:

```
ans4 = sr1(IP(dst=hostname) / ICMP())
ans6 = sr1(IPv6(dst=hostname) / ICMPv6EchRequest())
```

I am trying to parse the contents of ans4 and ans6.  In particular, I’d like to know if hostname actually responded with a ping reply.  I see ans4.show() and ans6.show() and ans6.summary() and ans6.summary() and a bunch of other methods and attributes, but I can’t seem to find what I am looking for.  I can parse repr(ans), which is a string, but is that the best way to do it?

Comment: IP doesn't use host names. DNS is used to resolve the host names to IP addresses, and the IP addresses are used for communication. Looking at captured packets will show the IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vaguely asked, but if I got you right - this should do the job:

```
>>> hostname = 'www.google.com'
>>> ans,unans=sr(IP(dst=hostname)/ICMP())
Begin emission:
.......Finished to send 1 packets.
..*
Received 10 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
>>> ans.summary( lambda(s,r): r.sprintf("%IP.src% : %ICMP.type%") )
216.58.208.100 : echo-reply
```

Comment: I'm familiar with the .show and .summary methods.  What I am looking for is something that will decode the fields in the packets.  Right now, what I am going is calling repr(ans4) and repr(ans6) and then parsing the resulting strings.  And that works, but it seems fragile and complicated to me.

Comment: Which field exactly you're looking to decode? ICMP replies? They're just different types. if you want to get this you can simply use: for s,r in ans: r[ICMP].type